# How to Json query in Ansible

Tags: python, arrays, json, ansible, jmespath

I am using **ec2_lc_facts** ansible module and registering the output to a variable called **lc_facts**.  I am able to grab the **block_device_mappings** value using json query **"{{ lc_facts.launch_configurations|json_query('[*].block_device_mappings') }}"** but want to grab the **volume_size** and **volume_type** from the following output.  Please help.

```
 "lc_facts": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "launch_configurations": [
            {
                "block_device_mappings": [
                    {
                        "device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
                        "ebs": {
                            "delete_on_termination": true, 
                            "volume_size": 40, 
                            "volume_type": "gp2"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
       ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lc_facts.launch_configurations|json_query('[*].block_device_mappings[0].ebs.[volume_size, volume_type]') }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": [
    [
        40, 
        "gp2"
    ]
]
```

To get hashes use this one

```
- debug:                                                                                                                          
    msg: "{{ lc_facts.launch_configurations|json_query('[*].block_device_mappings[0].ebs.{size: volume_size, type: volume_type}') }}"
```